# Regex value cbf in Go from abc.xyz.cbf201

Tags: regex, go

I am having issues creating a regex to return the string, `"foo"` from a given string `"abc.xyz.foo123"`. The `"foo"` can be any characters `[a-z]`, I am trying to capture after the last, but stop at the first digit (`1` in this example).

I have tried using regex pattern, `((\w{3})(\d{3}))` but this returns `"foo"` in groups and the full match returns `foo123`.

Comment: Why regexp? Why not strings.LastIndexByte to find the . and strings.LastIndexAny to find the last character? Regular expressions are fine but not always the clearest solution.

Comment: @Volker, LastIndexByte and LastIndexAny would not work for this case because "foo" is dynamic, it could be "foo", "bar", etc.

Comment: ?? the dot isn dynamic and LastIndexAny copes with arbitrary data. Did you read the doc of these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do this with a go-style expression without capturing. So I'd go for consuming all groups of characters followed by a period and then capture all letters until the first digit. For example:

```
^(?:\w+\.)+([a-z]+)\d
```

Output:

```
Full match  0-12    abc.xyz.foo1
Group 1.    8-11    foo
```